# Mapping a nested list with List Comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists, map-function

I have the following code which I use to map a nested list in Python to produce a list with the same structure.

```
>>> nested_list = [['Hello', 'World'], ['Goodbye', 'World']]
>>> [map(str.upper, x) for x in nested_list]
[['HELLO', 'WORLD'], ['GOODBYE', 'WORLD']]
```

Can this be done with list comprehension alone (without using the map function)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For nested lists you can use nested list comprehensions:

```
nested_list = [[s.upper() for s in xs] for xs in nested_list]
```

Personally I find `map` to be cleaner in this situation, even though I almost always prefer list comprehensions.  So it's really your call, since either will work.

Comment: in py3k map requires a list to be applied to it.

Answer (score 6):

Remember the Zen of Python:

> There is generally more than one -- and probably *several* -- obvious ways to do it.**

** Note: Edited for accuracy.

Anyway, I prefer map.

```
from functools import partial
nested_list = map( partial(map, str.upper), nested_list )
```

Comment: You mean : "There should be one– and preferably only one –obvious way to do it"? :)

Answer (score 4):

Map is certainly a much cleaner way of doing what you want. You can nest the list comprehensions though, maybe that's what you're after?

```
[[ix.upper() for ix in x] for x in nested_list]
```

Comment: Yes, it may be cleaner using map but I would like to use a generator.

Answer (score 2):

Other posters have given the answer, but whenever I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a functional construct, I swallow my pride and spell it out longhand with explicitly non-optimal methods and/or objects.  You said you wanted to end up with a generator, so:

```
for xs in n_l:
    def doUpper(l):
        for x in l:
            yield x.upper()
    yield doUpper(xs)

for xs in n_l:
    yield (x.upper() for x in xs)

((x.upper() for x in xs) for xs in n_l)
```

Sometimes it's cleaner to keep one of the longhand versions.  For me, map and reduce sometimes make it more obvious, but Python idioms might be more obvious for others.

Comment: This is a really good approach. It's also good to add unit tests if you're still not clear on how something might work. TDD is a great way to step through logic. While we are on the topic on the Zen of python "Readability counts."

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for ***nested list that has arbitrary depth***:

```
def map_nlist(nlist=nlist,fun=lambda x: x*2):
    new_list=[]
    for i in range(len(nlist)):
        if isinstance(nlist[i],list):
            new_list += [map_nlist(nlist[i],fun)]
        else:
            new_list += [fun(nlist[i])]
    return new_list
```

you want to upper case all you list element, just type

```
In [26]: nested_list = [['Hello', 'World'], ['Goodbye', [['World']]]]
In [27]: map_nlist(nested_list,fun=str.upper)
Out[27]: [['HELLO', 'WORLD'], ['GOODBYE', [['WORLD']]]]
```

And more important, this recursive function can do more than this!

I am new to python, feel free to discuss!

Comment: Use `append` instead of `+=`, to avoid recreating a new list for each item.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis Filippidis Hey thanks for reply, but can you give me more detail about the issue with +=? I don't quite understand the difference... (long time no use python ..)

Comment: Let `a = list()`. With `a.append(0)` the same `list` instance is extended with one more element. In contrast, `a += [0]` creates one new list `[0]` that is then dismissed from memory. Correction to my earlier comment: I thought that `__iadd__` worked like `__add__`, but using `id` revealed that it doesn't. More details can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add).

Comment: It's really smart!