# Different behaviour for list.__iadd__ and list.__add__

Tags: python, list

consider the following code:

```
>>> x = y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x += [4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

and then consider this:

```
>>> x = y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x = x + [4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why is there a difference these two?

(And yes, I tried searching for this).

Comment: What is interesting about your last statement, is that this functionality is actually explained in the python docs: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__  (from searching about those terms)

Comment: @jdl: Yes I admit that I overlooked that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`__iadd__` mutates the list, whereas `__add__` returns a *new* list, as demonstrated.

An expression of `x += y` first tries to call `__iadd__` and, failing that, calls `__add__` followed an assignment (see Sven's comment for a minor correction). Since `list` has `__iadd__` then it does this little bit of mutation magic.

Comment: If you want more details on this exact behavior and other insights into why Python is the way it is - I would highly recommend the [python epiphanies talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/613/python-epiphanies) from PyCon 2012. It will lead you to a lot of 'a ha!' moments.

Comment: @S Singh if you get your answer then please select the answer as accepted answer and complete the workflow. Otherwise this question will be shown as unanswered.

Comment: This answer is slightly misleading:  The assignment is always performed, regardless whether `__iadd__()` or `__add__()` is called.  `list.__iadd__()` simply returns `self`, though, so the assignment has no effect other than rendering the target name local to the current scope.

Comment: Also: `__iadd__` works faster for lists (it changes object in-place instead of recreating one); it allows to append any iterable, `a = []`   `a+=range(5)` works for lists, and `a = a + smth` requires `smth` to be an instance of list

Comment: @thodnev "it allows to append any iterable" -- Wow, this must be the first time I see this sort of type coercion between built-in types in 13 years of doing Python. It is beyond me how anyone would think it'd be a good idea to make `__add__` and `__iadd__` behave so surprisingly differently.

Answer (score 5):

The first mutates the list, and the second rebinds the name.

Answer (score 1):

1)'+=' calls ***in-place*** add i.e **iadd** method. This method takes two parameters, but makes the change in-place, modifying the contents of the first parameter (i.e x is modified). Since both x and y point to same Pyobject they both are same.

2)Whereas x = x + [4] calls the **add** mehtod(x.**add**([4])) and instead of changing or adding values in-place it creates a new list to which a points to now and y still pointing to the old_list.