# Why does adding to a list do different things?

Tags: python, list

```
>>> aList = []
>>> aList += 'chicken'
>>> aList
['c', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'n']
>>> aList = aList + 'hello'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    aList = aList + 'hello'
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I don't get why doing a `list += (something)` and `list = list + (something)` does different things. Also, why does `+=` split the string up into characters to be inserted into the list?

Comment: Another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9766387/776084.

Comment: @agf: no, that question is about `+=` vs. `+` in the face of multiple references to the same list.

Comment: Doesn't quite look like a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 5):

`list.__iadd__()` can take any iterable; it iterates over it and adds each element to the list, which results in splitting a string into individual letters. `list.__add__()` can only take a list.

Answer (score 5):

`aList += 'chicken'` is python shorthand for `aList.extend('chicken')`.  The difference between `a += b` and `a = a + b` is that python tries to call `iadd` with `+=` before calling `add`. This means that `alist += foo` will work for any iterable foo.

```
>>> a = []
>>> a += 'asf'
>>> a
['a', 's', 'f']
>>> a += (1, 2)
>>> a
['a', 's', 'f', 1, 2]
>>> d = {3:4}
>>> a += d
>>> a
['a', 's', 'f', 1, 2, 3]
>>> a = a + d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to be adding lists to lists, not strings to lists.

Try this:

```
a = []
a += ["chicken"]
a += ["dog"]
a = a + ["cat"]
```

Note they all work as expected.

Comment: No, as an _iterable_ of `str`ings.