# What do operator //= and :: do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I am working on the [Euler problems](https://projecteuler.net) and found this code online for the third problem.

I used Python 3 to solve the third and fourth problems.

```
def lpf(c):  # largest_prime_factor
    i = 2
    while i * i <= c:
        if c % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            c //= i            # c // i returns the integer quotient of c/i 
    return c
```

I know that the `//` returns the integer quotient of a division, but what is happening when an equal sign is put just after it?

`c //= i` --> Is the integer quotient of `c/i` affected to the variable `c`?

**Also**, I am working on palindromes for problem 4 and I found this operator `::`.

For example, here is code using it:

```
> s = str(12321)

> print(s == s[::-1])

Output : True
```

(If the number is a palindrome, then output is `True`, else the output is `False`.)

Is the operator `::` reading the string and changing it with an option? If so, how do you use it?

Comment: `c // = i` does exactly what you stated `c // i returns the integer quotient of c/i ` its just shorthand the same as `c += i`, `c -= i`, `c %= i` etcetera are. As for `s[::-1]` this is reversing the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read an operator like `??=` with `??` a special operator, that **usually** (not always), can be replaced by:

```
c ??= e
```

into:

```
c = c ?? e
```

So the operation is done **inplace**. So here you have written:

```
c = c // i    # equivalent to c //= i
```

Note that sometimes inplace operations differ from their non-inplace counterparts. For instance **for a list** [`la += lb` is **not** equal to `la = la + lb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19399555/67579). Since *numerical* values are immutable however, there is not much we can optimize here, so for numbers the above will (probably) always hold.