# where are operators mapped to magic methods in python?

Tags: python

I've been reading about magic methods in python, and I've found a lot of info about overriding them   and what purpose they serve, but I haven't been able to find where in the language specific operators and actions are mapped to those methods (`+` looks for `__add__`, `+=` looks for `__iadd__`, creating a new object from a class might call `__new__` and `__init__`, etc.)  Is there somewhere I can see what happens when the python interpreter (or whatever lower level mechanism) encounters a plus sign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit generic. There is a comprehensive [list](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) of "special methods", even though it misses some stdlib specific methods(e.g. `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` used by `pickle` etc. But it's a protocol of the module `pickle` not a language protocol).

If you want to know exactly what the interpreter does you can use the `dis` module to disassemble the bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def my_func(a):
...     return a + 2
... 
>>> dis.dis(my_func)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that the intereper executes a `BINARY_ADD` byte code when doing addition.
If you want to see exactly the operations that `BINARY_ADD` does you can download Python's source code and check the `ceval.c` file:

```
    case BINARY_ADD:
        w = POP();
        v = TOP();
        if (PyInt_CheckExact(v) && PyInt_CheckExact(w)) {
            /* INLINE: int + int */
            register long a, b, i;
            a = PyInt_AS_LONG(v);
            b = PyInt_AS_LONG(w);
            /* cast to avoid undefined behaviour
               on overflow */
            i = (long)((unsigned long)a + b);
            if ((i^a) < 0 && (i^b) < 0)
                goto slow_add;
            x = PyInt_FromLong(i);
        }
        else if (PyString_CheckExact(v) &&
                 PyString_CheckExact(w)) {
            x = string_concatenate(v, w, f, next_instr);
            /* string_concatenate consumed the ref to v */
            goto skip_decref_vx;
        }
        else {
          slow_add:
            x = PyNumber_Add(v, w);
        }
        Py_DECREF(v);
      skip_decref_vx:
        Py_DECREF(w);
        SET_TOP(x);
        if (x != NULL) continue;
        break;
```

So here we can see that python special cases int and string additions, and eventually falls back to `PyNumber_Add`, which checks if the first operand implements `__add__` and calls it, eventually it tries `__radd__` of the right hand side and if nothing works raises a `TypeError`.

Note that the byte codes are version-specific, so `dis` will show different results on different versions:

```
# python2.7
>>> def my_func():
...     return map((lambda x: x+1), range(5))
... 
>>> dis.dis(my_func)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (map)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x16f8c30, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             21 RETURN_VALUE        
# python3
>>> dis.dis(my_func)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (map) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x7f1161a76930, file "<stdin>", line 2>) 
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('my_func.<locals>.<lambda>') 
              9 MAKE_FUNCTION            0 
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range) 
             15 LOAD_CONST               3 (5) 
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

Also the same byte code may be optimized in future versions, so even if the byte code is the same different versions of python will actually perform different instructions.

If you're interested in learning how python works behind the scenes I'd advise you to write some C extensions, following the tutorials and documentation that you can find on the official python's website.

Answer (score 4):

It's non-trivial to pinpoint the single place in CPython sources mapping operator `+` to special method `__add__` because of the levels of abstraction involved.

As other responded, `+` is implemented with the [`BINARY_ADD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Python/ceval.c#L1380) opcode, which calls [`PyNumber_Add`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Objects/abstract.c#L955) (except in some specially optimized cases). `PyNumber_Add`, on the other hand, looks at the [`tp_as_number` member](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_as_number) of the [type object](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html) to get to the [`PyNumberMethods`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html#number-object-structures) struct whose `nb_add` member points to the C function that implements addition.

This is straightforward for built-in types which [define](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Objects/longobject.c#L3245) [their own](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Objects/floatobject.c#L534) `nb_add` directly, but a bit more convoluted for `__add__` defined in Python, which needs to be translated to an appropriate `nb_add`. This part is handled by `typeobject.c`: when you define a class that implements `__add__`, the machinery in `typeobject.c` [installs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Objects/typeobject.c#L7531) into `object->type->tp_as_number->nb_add` a generic function that looks up `__add__` on the object and calls it to implement the addition. For the case of `__add__`, this generic function is called `slot_nb_add` and is [defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Objects/typeobject.c#L6297) using the [`SLOT1BIN` macro](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Objects/typeobject.c#L6129).

As for `__new__` and `__init__`, they are invoked [from the `__call__` operator of the `type` object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36c41bc2017921321dbb19557f616a6bb7572c83/Objects/typeobject.c#L922) itself (`tp_call` in CPython-implementation lingo). This is only logical, since in Python you are calling the type to construct an object.

Answer (score 3):

[`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module can somewhat help you on this:

let's take an example of simple list:

```
In [12]: def func():
    lis=[1,2,3]
    for i in range(5):
        lis+=[i]
   ....:         

In [13]: def func1():
    lis=[1,2,3]
    for i in range(5):
        lis =lis + [i]
   ....:         

In [14]: dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)

             #removed some lines of code

  4          34 LOAD_FAST                0 (lis)
             37 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             40 BUILD_LIST               1
             43 INPLACE_ADD                       # += means inplace add is used
                                                  #     i.e `__iadd()__`
             44 STORE_FAST               0 (lis)
             47 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           28
        >>   50 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   51 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             54 RETURN_VALUE        

In [15]: dis.dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              9 BUILD_LIST               3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (lis)
             #removed some lines of code    
  4          34 LOAD_FAST                0 (lis)
             37 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             40 BUILD_LIST               1
             43 BINARY_ADD                          #normal binary add was used
                                                    #i.e __add__
             44 STORE_FAST               0 (lis)
             47 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           28
        >>   50 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   51 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             54 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Yes, but this is no way implies that `_iadd_` would be called for +=, the least I came across is [PEP 203](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/)

Comment: this is really cool to check out, but I guess I was hoping for the mapping of BINARY_ADD to `__add__`

Comment: @Abhijit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add, += is actually equivalent to `append()` in lists , which eventually calls `__iadd__()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: The accepted answer was quoted from PEP 203, which is what I said, the closest you can get. Dis, would not be helpful here

Comment: @Abhijit I think this is the the closest we can get using the interpreter itself, otherwise we need to dig into the C source code of python.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html

```
class x:
     def __add__(self,other):
          return "asd"

def test():
     return x() + "aaaa"



import dis
dis.dis(test)
```

which returns something like

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('aaaa')
              9 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

thats the closest you will come to "low level"

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this portion of the documentation:

http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names