# Can I get the name of the operator that triggered a special method?

Tags: python, magic-methods, hardcode

I am working in customizing the behaviour of Python native functions and operators in my classes. I would like to avoid hard coding when printing error messages like "'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'".
I know how to avoid hard coding of type names (by using `type(object).__name__`. But ¿how can I refer to the native function or operator that triggered my customized special method?

Here it comes an easy example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Person):
            raise TypeError("'<' not supported between instances of "
                            f"'{type(self).__name__}'"
                            f" and '{type(other).__name__}'")
        else:
            return self.age < other.age
        
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return not self < other
```

With this class definition I have:

```
>>> me = Person('Javier', 55)
>>> you = Person('James', 25)
>>> print(you < me)
True
>>> print(you >= me)
False
>>> print(you < 30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "....py", line 8, in __lt__
    raise TypeError("'<' not supported between instances of "
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Person' and 'int'
>>> print(you >= 30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "....py", line 15, in __ge__
    return not self < other
  File "....py", line 8, in __lt__
    raise TypeError("'<' not supported between instances of "
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Person' and 'int'
>>>
```

As you can see, I had to hardcode the name of the operator '<'. I usually avoid hard coding, but in this case I have an additional reason to avoid it: the TypeError message in operator >= is wrong as it says: '<' not supported between instances of 'Person' and 'int'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why return NotImplemented instead of raising NotImplementedError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplemented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror)

Comment: You don't need to (and should not) manually raise a `TypeError` to try to mimic the standard not-comparable messages. You can just return the `NotImplemented` singleton and let Python raise the actual `TypeError`.

Comment: Thank you, @Brian61354270, for your comment. I didn't know this behaviour when using NotImplemented. It helps a lot!!

Answer (score -3):

you could achieve this by defining an `operator` variable and then setting it to whatever it should be based on the conditions.

So something like this:

```py
x = 10

if x < 10: operator = "<"
elif x > 10: operator = ">"
else: operator = "=" 

print(f'you have used the {operator} operator')
```

You would need to pass the equivalent of this into whatever classes you decide to use this way.

Comment: *this is also hardcoding the operators*

Answer (score -3):

What you're asking here is 'How to get the method name from within the method so I can use to print it in a variable?'

This has been answered a bit here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067654/5005360

As the reference shows, the `inspect.stack()[0][3]` gets the name of the method that was just called.

First you need to map that for the method `__lt__` (and the others as well) you actually are using the '<' operator.

```
map_compar = {'__lt__' : '<', '__gt__': '>', '__eq__': '=='}
```

Then you create your Person class with your implementation (not included here)

```
class Person:
     def __lt__(self, value):

             #Gets the function name
             fn_name = inspect.stack()[0][3] 
             
             #Prints fn name with correct mapped operator
             print(f'You used the {map_compar[fn_name]} operator') 

     def __gt__(self, value):
             fn_name = inspect.stack()[0][3]
             print(f'You used the {map_compar[fn_name]} operator')

     def __eq__(self, value):
             fn_name = inspect.stack()[0][3]
             print(f'You used the {map_compar[fn_name]} operator')
```

And finally using it:

```
>>> person = Person()
>>> person < 10
You used the < operator
>>> person > 10
You used the > operator
>>> person == 10
You used the == operator
```

PS: This looks way too complicated of a solution for whatever you're doing. If it's just to prove a point and manipulate a class, fine, but if it's for something professional, you should think for a second if this is the best strategy.

Comment: This doesn't work as intended. For example, `1 < Person()` prints `You used the > operator`, and `1 <= Person()` raises an exception.

Comment: "What you're asking here is 'How to get the method name from within the method so I can use to print it in a variable?'" that is not what they are asking.

Comment: When you do 1 < Person(), it's the same as doing Person() > 1, so from the class perspective you are comparing is the person is greater than 1. So even though the answer seems backwards, it's always from the class perspective.

Comment: His question indeed is: "Can I get the name of the operator that triggered a special method?"

The *name of the operator*, would be "greater than", "less than"... 
What the OP wants is the *symbol* of the operator. Python doesn't have a lookup table that maps the method `__lt__` for example, back to '<' [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13334218/5005360). So this has to be mapped, and since the possibilities are not that many, it's a simple problem.
In my solution I return the symbol of the comparison operators that trigger that special method.

Comment: @Brian61354270, for the less or equal (<=) comparator, it wasn't implemented in the sample code above. You'd have just to code the `__le__` special method for it.

Comment: @danz As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, I think you're misreading the question. The OP is looking to match the operator in the error message with the operator in the code. The problem the OP is facing is that using `>=` in the code results in a `<` in the error message. This code arrives at the same wrong answer as the code in the question, just in a more roundabout way.

Comment: Thanks @Brian61354270 for the clarification. I was indeed misunderstanding the question. The issue is that Python, when running `10 > Person()` or `Person < 10` triggers the same method `__lt__`. How to differentiate the call from both since no other parameter is passed? Not sure.
If makes it better, I'm happy to delete my answer.