# strange python lists behaviour while addition

Tags: python

I tried following with python lists

```
a = [1,2,3]
id(a)
3072380812L
a += [1]
print id(a)
3072380812L  # Same id, which means original list is modified
a = a + [1]
print id(a)
146238764    # Different id, which means new list is allocated and assigned to a
```

Why is this difference between "var += value" and "var = var + value" for python lists ?

Comment: Also see [Different behaviour for list.\_\_iadd\_\_ and list.\_\_add\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9766387)

Comment: [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2347272/1831275)

Answer (score 3):

`+=` modifies(if mutable) ... as you have seen, and `=` assigns also as you have seen ...

both operators are overridable in the classes and their behavior can also be changed at the whims of developers... you could make = do summing if you wanted to ...

Comment: I mean why is this difference ? isn't var += 1 treated as var = var + 1 in all languages ?

Comment: no one modifies, the other assigns ... with ints it equates to the same since they are non mutable

Comment: "isn't var += 1 treated as var = var + 1 in all languages?" Python is a language, and it doesn't treat `+=` that way. So, obviously, no...