# Why does python list L += x behaves differently than L = L + x?

Tags: python, list, operators

```
ls = [1,2,3]
id(ls)
output: 4448249184  # (a)

ls += [4]
id(ls)
output: 4448249184  # (b)

ls = ls + [4]
id(ls)
output: 4448208584   # (c)
```

Why are (a) and (b) the same, but (b) and (c) are different?

Isn't `L += x` the same as `L = L + x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `+=`, you are modifying the list in plac, like when you use a class method that append `x` to `L` (like `.append`, `.extend`…). This is the [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) method.

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (+=, -=, *=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

Using `L = L + x`, you are creating a new list (`L+x`) that you are affecting to a variable (in this case `L`).

See also [different behaviour for list `__iadd__` and `__add__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add)

Answer (score 1):

Augmented assignment in List case is different.
it is not actual assignment like in integer so that

```
a += b
```

is equal to

```
a = a+b
```

while in case of List it operate like:

```
list += x
```

is:

```
list.extends(x)
```