# Function parameter is reference?

Tags: python, list, augmented-assignment

```
def add_list(p):
    p = p + [1]

p1 = [1, 2, 3]
add_list(p1)
print p1


res:[1, 2, 3]
```

BUT

```
def add_list(p):
    p += [1]

p1 = [1, 2, 3]
add_list(p1)
print p1

res:[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

I don't know why, can someone explain this? What's the main difference between them?

Comment: Linked as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add) which discusses exactly this behaviour. :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2347265/3001761. Augmented assignment gets even more interesting [with tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works)!