# Print Pass by Value in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The class is given below, this will print 20_20. Now till the line 5 code is same, I don't want the value of `T.a` to change when i change value of `T1.a`. How to solve it?

```
class Test: 
    def __init__(self, val): 
        self.a = val 

T = Test(10) 
T1 = T 
T1.a = 20 
print T.a + '__' + T1.a
```

Expected Output Is 10_20 .

Comment: That's not quite Python code. Also, `T1 = T` makes both names reference *exactly the same object*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the `copy` method of the `copy` module:

```
import copy
T = Test(20)
T1 = copy.copy(T)
T1.a = 40
print T.a
# Output 20
print T1.a
# Output 40
```

For more info check out the `copy` docs, https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 5):

In line `6. T1 = T`, you are telling python to make a new reference to object `T` called `T1`.

> i dont want the value of T.a to change when i change value of T1.a

This can't be done the way you set it up since T and T1 point to the same object. You can see this by noting that `T is T1` evaluates to `True` in the python interpreter.

It seems maybe that you want to instantiate 2 `Test` objects, each with its own `a` property, so that changing one object won't affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want to do is probably called "deep copying" https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

this allows you to create a copy of an existing object, instead of a reference. That is the closest thing to *pass by value*, I can think of, when using objects.

Answer (score 0):

By making **T1=T** you are making **both of them same** so if you change T1 it will affect T and vice versa . You could use copy,deep copy etc

```
class Test: 
    def __init__(self, val): 
        self.a = val 

T = Test (10) 
T1 = Test(20) 
print str(T.a) + '__' + str(T1.a)
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152195/python-multiple-assignment-and-references/31153595#31153595) for more on mutuable and non-mutable object assignment and value changing