# Adding to lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4]
>>> D = A
>>> D
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> D = D + [5]
>>> A
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> C = A
>>> C += [5]
>>> A
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Why does `C += [5]` modifies `A` but `D = D + [5]` doesn't?

Is there any difference between `=` and `+=` in python or any other language in that sense?

Comment: When you use `D = D + [5]` you create a new list object with the same name. When you use `D += [5]` you alter the existing list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different behaviour for list.\_\_iadd\_\_ and list.\_\_add\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually yes there is. When you use `+=` you're still referencing to the same object, however with `+` you're creating a new object, and with `=` you reassign the reference to that newly created object. This is especially important when dealing with function arguments. Thanks to @Amadan and @Peter Wood for clarifying that.

Comment: The `=` doesn't create the new object. `=` modifies the name to reference another object.

Comment: It's not the `=` that creates a new object, it's the `+`. `D = D + [5]` invokes `D = D.__add__([5])`; `C += [5]` invokes `C.__iadd__([5])`. `__add__` creates a new object, `__iadd__` does not; `=` just assigns the reference.

Comment: In this case you are right but let's discuss a little bit broader example, let's say we have a list `a=[1,2,3]` and we pass it to the function `def f(l=a): l=[1,2,3,4]`. We aren't using any `+` operators here, however the global `a` isn't altered. It's the `=` operator that you should mostly care about, because it creates a new reference, like @Peter Wood said.

Comment: @Nhor I'm not sure I agree. You're becoming less clear the more words you type (c: Your broader example doesn't really make a point.

Comment: @Amadan said that it's not the `=` operator that reassings the reference but `+`, so I posted a simple example where `+` isn't used however the reference is reassigned (due to `=` usage). What's unclear about that?

Comment: @Nhor: I have not said that `=` reassigns the reference. I said `=` does not create a new object. I have no idea how you managed to misunderstand me and misquote me so completely.