# python list: append vs +=

Tags: python, list, append

For Python list, is `append()` the same as `+=`?
I know that `+` will lead to the creation of a new list, while `append()` just append new stuff to the old list.
But will `+=` be optimized to be more similar to `append()`? since they do the same thing.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. `+=` concatenates, is more like `extend()` rather than `append()`.

Comment: they are not the same, see duplicates for details.

Comment: the `+=` operator acts *in-place* on the left-hand operand. The `+` operator creates a *new list* from both operands, and neither is modified in place. `.append` accepts a *single element* which it appends to the end of the list. So, `+=` acts like `.extend` (and probably calls the same function under the hood)

Answer (score 1):

It's an `__iadd__` operator. [Docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)

Importantly, this means that it only *tries* to append. "For instance, if x is an instance of a class with an `__iadd__()` method, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)` . Otherwise, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`."

[This thread specifically deals with lists and their iadd behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add)