# Understanding Python's builtins operator overloading behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

**list & tuples behavior on `+` and `+=` operator overloading:**

this fails:

```
>>> [1,2] + (3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

but this works:

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l += (3,4)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**with set & frozenset things behave differently:**

this works:

```
>>> {1,2} | frozenset({3,4})
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

this also works:

```
>>> s = {1,2}
>>> s |= frozenset({3,4})
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Why `[1,2] + (3,4)` dont work similarly to `{1,2} | frozenset({3,4})`?

Why the two differ? is there a reason for this? is it a backward compatibility thing or something related to internals?

I'm more interested in *why* its implemented like this not *what* technically happens under the hood. I suspect that the Python language designed with some careful thinking and there is a reason for this difference which i want to understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add

Comment: @ReutSharabani it is a different question, not a dupe. This asks why `[1, 2] + (3, 4)` doesn't work as `[1, 2] += (3, 4)`. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @sanyash I reopened already although its very close. I agree this asks for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is the implementation which isn't consistent and very annoying.

In this example:

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l += (3,4)
```

One would expect `l += (3, 4)` to translate to `l = l + (3, 4)` and fail, but the `list.__iadd__`/`set.__iadd__` implementation is different and **mutates the original object**. But it actually translates to roughly:

```
l.extend((3, 4))
```

And by caliing `list.extend` it can be called with (probably) any iterable:

```
>>> l = [1]
>>> l += {11, 31, 21} # <--- this should be a lot more troubling (no order)
>>> l
[1, 11, 21, 31] # worked, but obviously no order guarantees
```

This is probably done for efficiency reasons, but it is implicit and very error-prone. It makes this idiomatic code pattern:

```
l = []
for items in items_generator:
    l += items
```

Scale *much* better without the user having to think about it.

The custom implementations (`iadd(x, y)`, `or_(x, y)`) for native data structures are exceptions made for performance reasons.

Comment: thanks @Reut but im looking for a reason why its like this in terms of design decision of the python language. this works fine: `x = [1,2];y=[3,4];x+y`  creating a new 3rd list so its possible to implement it i guess there is another decision (maybe strongly type concerns?)

Comment: @ShmulikA I believe both are done for efficiency. This way the `__iadd__` implementations do not need to copy the list (since python has no structural sharing, it has to copy the entire list to do `l = l + [1]`).

Comment: thanks for the technical explanation but its not my question. `[1] + (1,)` fails while `[1] + [1]` works - regardless of efficiency. its design decision to not support this operation. `x + [1]` works. why not support `list + tuple` and only support `list + list` while += supported by both. why its differ from `set + frozenset`? its not  a matter of mutability (set is mutable) or efficiency (it returns TypeError)

Comment: @ShmulikA I've elaborated my answer a bit, but it practically remains the same. The way I see it, exceptions were made in the implementations  of native data structures for performance reasons of idiomatic code. Maybe I just don't understand the question. Good luck anyway :)