# Id of list is changing when I use list=list+something but not changing when I use list+=something (in Python)

Tags: python, list

In the process of understanding mutability and immutability concepts, I was trying out different things and came across this:

When I wrote a simple code shown below (I will refer to this as code 1):

---

```
c=[1,2,3]
print(id(c))
c=c+[5]
print(c)
print(id(c))
```

---

The output is this:

```
1911612356928
[1, 2, 3, 5]
1911611886272
```

And when I wrote the code (I will refer to this as code 2):

---

```
c=[1,2,3]
print(id(c))
c+=[5]
print(c)
print(id(c))
```

---

The output is this:

```
1911612356928
[1, 2, 3, 5]
1911612356928
```

As `c` is a list which is mutable in python, I expected the ID to remain the same in code 1 and was confused by the output. Changing the syntax from `c+=[5]` to `c=c+[5]` in code gave me a different output where the ID of `c` did not change though I am performing the same operation on `c` as in code 1.

1. Why is the id of `c` changing in the first case and not in the second?
2. Isn't `c+=[5]` equivalent to `c=c+[5]`?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add , but that link doesn't explain why they chose to design it this way. I haven't watched it yet, but someone posted this link as a comment on that answer suggesting it might explain the reasoning behind this design choice: https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/python-epiphanies.html. Also read this paragraph https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ior__ which explains that the inplace methods should return `self` where they can.

Comment: Because `c += [5]` adds a new element to the same list, the other concattenates two list and assigns the (changed) result back to the name of one of those 2 lists - but the `c+[5]` is still a new list thats assigned to be known as `c` for then on

Answer (score 3):

`c += 5` and `c = c + [5]` produce the same value of `c`, but the implementation is slightly different.

`c += 5` is a single statement that is implemented by effectively `append`ing `5`to `c`.  That is, the existing `c` list is extended in-place; its `id` does not change.

`c = c + [5]` contains two statements.  The first one is `c + [5]`, which creates a new list (distinct from the original `c`).  The second is the assignment, which assigns the right operand (the new list created by the `c + [5]` expression) to the name `c`.  Since c has been reassigned to point to a new list, its `id` is now different.

Another way to look at it is that `c = c + [5]` is the same as:

```
temp = c + [5]
c = temp
```

Comment: An assignment is *not* an expression. It is a statement in and of itself. `c += 5` is *also* a statement, not an expression.

Comment: @chepner I'll take your word for it!  :)