# Python mutable object concatenation to list

Tags: python, list, concatenation, iterable, mutable

I have these lines of code and I don't understand why does it work.

```
list_ = []
string = '12345'
for i in string:
    list_ += i
print(list_)
#Output: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

People say this is the magic of python and I have this link below, but I do not have sufficient background in C
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/998ae1fa3fb05a790071217cf8f6ae3a928da13f/Objects/listobject.c#L977

Edit: The question is why this does not rise an exception? **string** is not a list, it is an iterable

```
first_list = [] + 'a'
print(first_list)

#TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it work?  In what way were you expecting this to fail?

Comment: Are you confused by the `for i in string:` part? A string variable, like many types in Python is an iterable, which means you can iterate over its parts. Other examples are tuples, lists, but also specialised types like the pair in a dict when using `.items()`.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Explain this block of code to me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  *Specifically* what do you not understand?  Trace the values like you're supposed to, and describe just what confuses you.  This is straightforward iteration and concatenation; Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: `str` is a [text sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

Comment: Because `+=` is documented as being equivalent to `.extend`, and `.extend` accepts any iterable

Answer (score 0):

I assume you understand this part:

```
for i in string:
```

Therefore I will focus on this:

```
list_ += i
```

It works because in python there is no `char`type. In python a single character is still a string. And a string is "iterable". And a list can be "extended" by an iterable.

```
list += another_list
```

means

```
list.extend(another_list)
```

E.g. this will not work:

```
list += 1
```

since `1` is just a single number, while

```
list += 'a'
```

will work fine because 'a' is not a character but a string which in turn is an iterable.

There are better explanations of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add).

Answer (score -1):

A string is an iterable because the `str` class/type implements the `__iter__` method. By implementing the `__iter__` method, the for-loop is able to iterate all members in the string. Whenever the for-loop asks for the next element in the string, Python's `str` class's iterable returns it's string instance's next character. As a result, `i`, in the context of the for-loop, is always the next character in the string.

Within the loop, `list_ += i` class works because Python's `list` class/type implements the `__iadd__` method. `__iadd__` is a method that is called whenever Python encounters the `+=` operator. Normally, the `__iadd__` operation of `list` is used to add elements from one iterable to the end of a list instance. Because the method is meant to combine iterables, you would receive a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` if your code was the following:

```py
list_ = []
string = '12345'
for i in string:
    list_ += int(i)
print(list_)
```

However, your code works because, going back to the first discussion point, in Python, strings are iterables. As a result, it is perfectly legal in Python to say:

```py
l=[]
s='omg'
l+=s
print(l)
# Output: ['o', 'm', 'g']
```

You might think your case is different than my example above because your case is looping over each character in the string rather than working with the string itself. However, Python does not have a character type, so effectively, every character (`i`) is a single-character string. As a result, every individual character `i` in your for-loop has its own `__iter__` method, effectively allowing the character to be appended to the end of `list_`, as if the operation said: `list += [i]`.

Comment: first_list = [] + 'a'
print(first_list)
#TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list;
  Question:why this block of code raise an exception. When we want to add manually

Comment: You are missing the crucial point, this *doesn't* work because of `__add__` but because of `__iadd__` When using just `some_list + some_iterable` then `__add__` *will* throw a TypeError, because it only accepts lists.