# Why does this code not give a concatenate str+list Type runtime error?

Tags: join, typeerror, assignment-operator

```
res=[]
res+=''.join(['a','b'])
print(res)

#output>>>['a', 'b']
```

---

but when I do:

```
res=[]
res=res+''.join(['a','b'])
print(res)
```

#it gives type error as expected

Comment: is that python?

Comment: I assume `__iadd__` takes an iterable and adds all the elements to the list, without creating a new list

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add may shed some light to what is happening